# Express doesn't load static files from the public folder in routes with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, static

I'm trying to render a page, but the static files are not being loaded by Express only on routes with a single parameter

Static configuration:
`app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "public")));`

Route:
`routes.get("/param/:id", (req, res) => res.render("page"));`

Error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:port/param/1/assets/js/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I've tried everything; maybe it has something to do with the structure of my project?

Repo: [projeto-agenda](https://github.com/edulustosa/projeto-agenda)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change your `static` to:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

2. Inside your view file change your links to always start with a `/` eg:

```html
<script src="/assets/js/bundle.js"></script>
```